# Removing whitespace of \draw plot command

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, draw, white-space

I use the following command to generate a smooth curve inside a Tikz picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black] plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,-0.5) (1,2.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It produces a nice curve, but adds additional whitespace at the figures borders. Is there a way to tighten the produced layout so that no additional whitespace is produced?

[image: Generated by the command above]

Comment: The white space you're experiencing is due to the (invisible) construction of the curve. If you know about Bezier curves, you should see how the tension is applied to the curve depending on control points. In order to cut this extra space, you can use `\clip`. And please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comments, you'll have to use clipping to reduce the extra space around your drawing:

[image: clipping extra space]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,-1.05) rectangle (1.3,2.5);
        \draw[black] plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,-0.5) (1,2.5)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT: a bit of explanation

Here you can see how your curve is constructed (controls points and tensions). This would explain why you have this extra space around your picture:

[image: explanation]